# Error adding Device plugin with Phonegap 3

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using Phonegap's Command Line Interface to create and build Phonegap apps. The version I am using is 3.1.0-0.15.0. I need to install the Device plugin to simply find out what platform the app is currently running on. I did this with the following command:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device
```

This worked fine and Device plugin is successfully installed. In config.xml I see:

```
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
```

I then build the android app:

```
phonegap local build android
```

However, when I run on a device I get the following error:

```
W/System.err(24625): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.device.Device
W/System.err(24625):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err(24625):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)

...
```

and:

```
I/System.out(26075): Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.device.Device.
D/PluginManager(26075): exec() call to unknown plugin: Device
```

When I run:

```
phonegap local plugin list
```

I get:

```
[phonegap] com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.device
```

I have cleaned the project a number of times. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add phonegap plugin manually. Same happen to scandit barcode phoegap plugin.

https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin